# Maximizing the area for a UIImageView in portrait orientation, keeping it above the superview's center Y point

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uiimage, center, landscape-portrait

WHAT WORKS:

I have a UIViewController that has a UIImage on the left when in landscape orientation. I want the image to be large as possible, but it should not extend beyond the left-half the scene. It seems that you can do this by adding a constraint requiring that the superview's "Center X Between Margins" value to always be greater than or equal to the image's trailing edge.

WHAT DOESN'T WORK:

Similarly, the same UIImage should be at the top of the scene in portrait orientation. The image should be large but not to extend below the top half of the scene. I expected to add a constraint requiring the superview's "Center Y Between Margins" value to be greater than or equal to the image's bottom edge, but it is not obvious how to make this happen. A cntl-drag from the image down to the superview creates a constraint between the image's bottom and the "Bottom Layout Guide.Top". I checked the Size Inspector for an option to replace this with Superview.CenterYWithinMargins, but had no luck.

Instead, if you go to the Size Inspector and click on the "Bottom Layout Guide.Top" then there is option "Center Y" but it is grayed out. I suspect that the Bottom Layout Guide is not the object to use, but have not found a mechanism for specifying other objects.

QUESTIONS:

What is the best way to constrain a UIImageView (or any view, for that matter) so it's bottom edge does not extend below the superviews center Y?

Any idea why the landscape constraint options are so different from the portrait constraint options?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first proposition:

> I want the image to be large as possible, but it should not extend beyond the left-half the scene

You have not explained exactly where the image view is to go, but let's presume, for purposes of discussion, that it is to be at the top left. Then it will have these four constraints:

- top pinned to superview top
- left pinned to superview left
- width set equal to superview width but with a multiplier of 1/2
- aspect ratio (the ratio between width and height) set to the aspect ratio of the image itself

Now let's take the second proposition:

> at the top of the scene in portrait orientation. The image should be large but not to extend below the top half of the scene

Again, I assume we are at the top left. Then the constraints are:

- top pinned to superview top
- left pinned to superview left
- height set equal to superview height but with a multiplier of 1/2
- aspect ratio (the ratio between width and height) set to the aspect ratio of the image itself

As you can see, just one constraint needs to be swapped out on rotation between landscape and portrait. And this can be configured with no code (for an iPhone; for an iPad you would need code to make the swap).

Here are screen shots of the result. In portrait, we don't extend below the top half:

[image]

In landscape, we don't extend beyond the left half:

[image]

Comment: If that isn't what you want, the problem is that you didn't describe it well enough. Describe it better and I'll be glad to modify.

Comment: Thank you, Matt!  The use of the multiplier never occurred to me. My apologies for not providing the data you asked about.  There is a tricky balance between "providing enough" and "inflicting too much"!